# Proving $\sqrt{p} \notin Q$ using slightly different steps.

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, divisibility

Question:

If p is a prime number, prove that $\sqrt{p} \notin\Bbb Q$.

My attempt:

The other answers I've seen so far use proof by contradiction but their steps are a little different. I just want to confirm if the following way is correct:

Proof by contradiction:

Assume $ \sqrt{p}$ is rational. Then, $ \sqrt{p} = \frac{m}{n}$ where $ m,n \in \Bbb Z$, $n\neq 0$, and $m$ and $n$ have no common factors.

$$\begin{align} \sqrt{p} = \frac{m}{n} &\implies p = \frac{m^{2}}{n^{2}} \\&\implies n^{2}p = m^{2} \\&\implies p\mid m^{2} \\&\implies p\mid m\cdot m \\&\implies p\mid m \qquad\text{since $p$ is prime.} \\&\implies \exists a \in \Bbb Z : m = ap\end{align}$$

We know $$ \begin{align}n^{2}p = m^{2} &\implies n^{2}p = a^{2}p^{2} \\&\implies n^{2} = a^{2}p \\&\implies p\mid n\cdot n \\&\implies p\mid n \qquad\text{since $p$ is prime}\end{align}$$ This is a contradiction since $m,n$ have no common factors.

Comment: seems okay to me other than spacing.

Comment: Proof looks good.

Comment: A more general result, we a different approach http://rtybase.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/regarding-square-root-of-n.html

Comment: What is "different"? This is one of the most common proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those seem like the same steps to me. We can summarize the argument as follows.

1. Write $\sqrt{p} = \frac mn$
2. Rearrange as $pn^2 = m^2$
3. Use some property about primes (e.g. $p\mid ab \to p \mid a \text{ or } p \mid b$ or alternatively, unique prime factorization) to conclude that $p \mid m$ and $p \mid n$.
4. Reach a contradiction by infinite descent.

So that argument is correct and you may also like to try using unique prime factorization to prove it.

Comment: how can I use prime factorization to prove it?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel The number of times a prime factor appears in a square is even but the number of times $p$ appears as a factor of $pn^2$ is odd.